# Error in SQL Syntax when simply trying to connect to the databank (beginner)

Tags: php, mysql

I already used some solutions put forward in other threads but it just doesn't want to work. My MYSQL version is: 5.5.38 and here is the code I use (the goal is to simply connect to the database). The code goes on, that's why the "{" is not closed from the if-clause, but the important part that should connect to the database is listed below:

```
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
$password = ($_POST['password']);

if ($_POST['user'] <> "" AND $_POST['password'] <> "")
{
mysql_connect('localhost', 'xxx', 'xxx');
mysql_select_db('xxx');

$sql = "SELECT * AS user FROM xxx WHERE nutzer LIKE '$nutzer' AND pw LIKE '$password'" ;

$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (false === $result) {
die (mysql_error());
}

$datensatz = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
```

These errors come right at the beginning when I just open the site:

> Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /var/www/web1159/html/lehrer.php on line 15
>
> Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be established in /var/www/web1159/html/lehrer.php on line 15

And this is the error on which I stumble when I try to log in and connect to the database. I know what it says, but it does not make much sense to me - are the " or ' wrongly placed? I tried other variations - still doesn't work. And why line 1??:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS user FROM lehrerzugang WHERE nutzer LIKE '' AND pw LIKE 'lfb'' at line 1

Comment: The error says it all: **Access denied for user ''@'localhost'**. Have you tried to connect to your database from command line? It seems your database is either unreachable or your credentials are bad. YOur SQL is false as well. As far as I know MySQL does not know the 'AS' keyword. Try the following `SELECT columnname user FROM xxx WHERE nutzer LIKE '$nutzer' AND pw LIKE '$password'` where columnname has to be replaced by your actual column name

Comment: First, the `mysql` php driver is deprecated; you should use either `mysqli` or `PDO_mysql`. Second, you can't call `mysql_real_escape_string()` until *after* you establish a database connection.

Comment: Whether you can use mysqli depends on which version of php you have installed, but it should be available by default in any php after 5.3.

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax mysqli was introduced in PHP 5.0 and not 5.3

Comment: @KAD True, but it was an option before 5.3, not standard equipment.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have implemented your suggestions and will have a look at mysqli. I think the login page works now, though it does not forward the sessions variable from the `$_session['user']`, which should actually include the username that was used beforehand to log in. When the next page (after you logged in) comes up, it does not echo the session variable, but I guess I have to test some more..

Answer (score 1):

Setup your database connection before calling `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Besides the default username and passowrd for localhost are `'root'` and empty string `''`, so unless you have explicitly changed these credentials you need to provide the access as root user with empty sting password.

```
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('yourDatabase');
```

If you have setup your own user access to the database then make sure you provide the correct credentials.

`mysql` functions are now deprecated in PHP and there is an Improved MYSQL library to support database connection and muanipulation [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), so use it.

You cannot give an alias to all columns selection `*` so `SELECT * AS` is invalid, aliases can be given to specific column selection `SELECT dateOfBirth AS DOB, dateCreated AS DC FROM yourTable`

Comment: mysqli was introduced in PHP version 5.0, so since you have version (5.5.38) you can simply use it without any configuration.